# add already developed aspx page in SharePoint site

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

I have the .aspx page which is already developed in VS 2008 with its code behind.
page name is say login.aspx.

Also have another page in same scenario after login this second page will appear. ok?

I want to embed/ add this already developed aspx page to above team site.

Comment: Why did you post a link to your **local** server?

Comment: so whats the matter? it is given only for its structure and scenario for visualize issue. and kind for information it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways:

- Create a Web Part Page and add a `Page Viewer Web Part`
- Create a blank page and add a IFRAME using Sharepoint Designer

Comment: why this ? is this not possible to add my developed aspx page in sharepoint site page list?

Comment: It should be noted that the default CAS policies in effect prevent ASPX pages with code behinds from executing in a Page library.

Answer (score 0):

If the Adrian's solution is not for you.. look into SmartPart webpart. That way you'll just turn your aspx page into a usercontrol and add it into a webpart zone and publish the page.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use SharePoint Designer and add it to site manually, thus not using any webpart as placeholder.